# how to show/hide two seperate DIVs outside of ech other by mouse hover with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

how i can show/hide two seperate DIVs by mouse hover when they are'nt inside each other. i have this:

```
<div class="a">
          <img src="/hoverme.jpg"/>
          <br/>
          <p>hover me</p>
</div>
///////////// some codes here ////////////////
<div class="b">
          <p>this will be show</p>
</div>
```

for css:

```
.a {
     background-color: #323232;
     width: 200px;
     height: 300px;
     color: #FFF;
}

.b {
     background-color: #0000ff;
     font-size:12px;
     color: #FFF;
}
```

I also tried this but it does not work:

```
.b {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.a:hover .b {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you have to use pseudo property :hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an inner child you need a script, e.g. if to hover the `p` inside `.a` and then show `.b`.

```js
document.querySelector('.a > p').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  this.closest('div').classList.add('over');
});
document.querySelector('.a > p').addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
  this.closest('div').classList.remove('over');
});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: #323232;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.b {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.b {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.a.over ~ .b {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="/hoverme.jpg" />
  <br/>
  <p>hover me</p>
</div>
///////////// some codes here ////////////////
<div class="b">
  <p>this will be show</p>
</div>
```

---

For siblings, use the CSS general sibling selector `~`

```
.a:hover ~ .b {...}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.a {
  background-color: #323232;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.b {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.b {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.a:hover ~ .b {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="/hoverme.jpg" />
  <br/>
  <p>hover me</p>
</div>
///////////// some codes here ////////////////
<div class="b">
  <p>this will be show</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not "go upwards" in selectors you have to bind the hover to the parent .a div but this should work.

In your css you used the descendant selector I used the sibbling selector

```
div.b {
    /* Hide by default */
    display: none;
}

div.a:hover ~ div.b {
   display: block;
}
```